# Unbelievable duplicate in an Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, duplicates

My SQL query against a particular view returns me 3 different rows.

```
 select * from vwSummary
 where vidate >= '10-15-2010' and vidate <= '10-15-2010'
 and idno = '0330'
 order by viDate
```

But if i run the same query through my entity framework, I get 3 rows but all the 3 rows are same, equivalent to the third row.

```
        firstVisibleDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 15);

        lastVisibleDate = new DateTime(2010, 10, 15);

var p1 = (from v in db.vwSummary
                     where v.viDate >= firstVisibleDate && v.viDate <= lastVisibleDate
                     && v.IDNo == "0330"
                          select v).ToList();
```

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue.

**EDIT:**
I changed my query like this and it works. But still I want to go back to the one shown above as I have to iterate again for more processing.

```
List<objectName> p1 = (from v in db.vwSummary
                     where v.viDate >= firstVisibleDate && v.viDate <= lastVisibleDate
                     && v.IDNo == "0330"
                          select new <ObjectName>
{
a = v.a
b = v.b
}
).ToList<ObjectName>();
```

Comment: bit of a wild guess, but it might be that the DateTime defined in code includes the time as midnight, whereas the DateTime defined in the SQL just defines the days. i.e. you SQL is returning everything for that day, but the code is returning everything for midnight. Dunno why you get the same number of results though.

Comment: Ye, that still puzzle me. I tried playing with the datetime, but couldnt find a clue.

Comment: I tried rebuliding entitymodel, just to nake sure that they are in sync. Still no success.

Comment: See what happens with separate where clauses all next to each other instead of &&. `where v.viDate >= firstVisibleDate` `where v.viDate <= lastVisibleDate` `where v.IDNo == "0330"` I don't know if this will make a difference but it is worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks Chevex, but that didnt help. Infact that was not there, I added IDno == 0330 for debugging to narrow down to actually see whats happening (like the date.).

Comment: I noticed one difference in the queries is you don't order by viDate in the second one. I don't know if that makes a difference with your issue.

Comment: Thanks again for trying Chevex. But that didnt belp.

Comment: My guess is that the problem lies in how you're then *using* the results, which you haven't shown.

Comment: Can you show us more code? Like how you iterate over var p1? Edit: lol, +1 jon

Comment: I will show handling the results as well. But even before that, I watch the variable p1 in degugger wathcer and expanded the list, I could see all the 3 objects same with the same information.

Comment: I will show the view I am using as well, if its required.

Comment: More information is always better :)

Comment: I tried changing the data, the scenario where I have to receive 5 rows, I receive 5 same rows. This is true for any number of rows.

Comment: I caught the query that EF executes, and I executed that query in SQL query editor, the query executes fine. So something in the mapping might be screwed up?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had a similar issue and I solved it by changing the merge option of the ObjectSet.
Example:

```
    using (TargetDBDataContext db = new TargetDBDataContext())
    {
        db.SomeView.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
        return db. SomeView.ToList();
    }
```

It looks like entity framework(EF) doesn’t handle correctly views that have duplicated primary keys or no primary keys at all. So when there are two rows that EF is considering equal, EF will load first row as it should but will not load the second row because it will consider it’s already loaded.

Comment: You can also try replacing db.SomeView in your entity query with db.SomeView.AsNoTracking().  This worked for me with EF5.

Comment: I added a primary key to the view and all was well. As the OP said  -"Unbelievable" was how I felt when I saw the problem.

Comment: `MergeOption` doesn't appear to be valid in EF any more, need to use `AsNoTracking()` instead.

Comment: Entity framework uses an "Identity Map", which constructs at most one instance per id per DbContext. In other words, two separate Linq queries "where id == 1" in the same DbConext will return the same runtime instance of the entity.  It basically checks the map to see if one with that id has already been constructed and returns it.  Every "entity" you load becomes tracked in the context's change tracker (unless you call AsNoTracking or return an anonymous type like 'select new { x.a, x.b }'). You cannot use non-unique keys as the entity id, because they'll both map to the same instance.

Answer (score 9):

Entity Framework exposes a number of  performance tuning options to help you optimise the performance of your applications. One of these tuning options is .AsNoTracking(). This optimisation allows you to tell Entity Framework not to track the results of a query. This means that Entity Framework performs no additional processing or storage of the entities which are returned by the query. However it also means that you cant update these entities without reattaching them to the tracking graph.

***You can set AsNoTracking option directly on your view to resolve this issue.***

context.viewname.**AsNoTracking()**.Where(x => x.ColumnName != null);

Answer (score 2):

Set entity key on the entity model of the view. This worked for me in two separate instances. You can use one or more properties in the key.

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**: I changed my query like this and it works. But still I want to go back to the one shown above as I have to iterate again for more processing.

```
List<objectName> p1 = (from v in db.vwSummary
                     where v.viDate >= firstVisibleDate && v.viDate <= lastVisibleDate
                     && v.IDNo == "0330"
                          select new <ObjectName>
{
a = v.a
b = v.b
}
).ToList<ObjectName>();
```

I found the source of the problem from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001847/duplicate-rows-when-data-binding-with-linq-to-entities) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598353/entity-framework-returning-different-data-then-db-query). I guessed this should be an issue as I didnt have a very good key in my view as the view was more of a summary report. So I am sticking to the workaround I found in my other answer.

So if you find a similar issue, the problem is, add a proper primary key to your table or the view. If you cannot add one try something similar to the work around.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this issue and thought it was my implementation until I found this post. The only workaround I managed to get working was to actually run the sqlquery as follows:-

```
using(var db = new Tpr.Models.MyContext())
{
    var model = _uow._context.Database.SqlQuery<MyTable>(string.Format("select * from MyTable where ID = '{0}'", "12345678"));

    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
}
```