# Entity Framework - entity using a view giving duplicate data

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-6, sql-view

I have the following view (SQL Server 2012 if it matters):

```
SELECT
 EntityId
,EntityType
,StateId
FROM
 SomeTable 
 INNER JOIN SomeOtherTable
```

When I generate an entity for this view (EF 6 - database first) it looks like this in the EDMX file:

```
<EntityType Name="VW_MyView">
   <Key>
      <PropertyRef Name="EntityId" />
      <PropertyRef Name="EntityType" />
   </Key>
   <Property Name="EntityId" Type="Int32" Nullable="false" />
   <Property Name="EntityType" Type="String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="2" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false" />
   <Property Name="StateId" Type="Int32" />
</EntityType>
```

As you can see, the model generator created an entity key on the first two columns. The problem is, the first two columns do not guarantee uniqueness.

So for example I could have data like this in the view:

```
EntityId   EntityType   StateId
--------   ----------   -------
1234       CR           1
1234       CR           2
1234       CR           3
```

When I query the data using linq such as:

```
using (ContextA context = new ContextA())
{
    var zList = context.VW_MyView.Where(f => f.EntityId == 1234 
                                    && f.EntityType == "CR").ToList();
}
```

I get a list of three items, but like this (notice stateid duplicated):

```
EntityId   EntityType   StateId
--------   ----------   -------
1234       CR           1 <-- dupe
1234       CR           1 <-- dupe
1234       CR           1 <-- dupe
```

I migrated this exact same code from EF 4 (object context templates) to EF 6 (dbcontext templates), and before the migration it did not perform like this.

I know I can manually add an EntityKey to the `StateId` column, and it will work properly, but I have over 100 views in my model and I don't want to go through each one to check.

Why has this behavior changed, and is there a setting I can enable (globally) to correct this?

**EDIT:**

So based on the answers, I have been able to gather three ways to prevent this issue.

1. Add all primary key values from each consisting table into the view
2. Use `nullif()` tricks in the view to force columns to be non-nullable, and those be added by EF to the key
3. Manually add the Entity Key in the model myself

But this doesn't explain really why this happens, and how it could possibly be desired behavior? The EF linq query is simply returning entirely incorrect data, without any exceptions or warnings. I can't imagine this is correct.

Comment: Does running the same query in T-SQL provide the same 3 results?

Comment: Is the StateId ever null? The designer did not include StateId property as part of the key since it is marked as nullable. If it in fact is not nullable you could cheat in the edmx and mark it as non-nullable and include as a key. Also, if you include the StateId property - will it make the composite key unique always?

Comment: @mxmissile - running the query in SQL returns the correct results (with stateid 1, 2 and 3).

Comment: @Pawel - StateId is never null. I don't mind if it didn't mark it as a key, I just don't see how EF is correct to return 3 rows with the "wrong" data in this case.

Comment: How does the query created by EF looks like? What is the result when executing the query against SQL Server? Finally is the INNER JOIN in the view definition needed and how it affects the results?

Comment: I have the same "issue" in EF4 (with an `.edmx`) - not sure why it worked for you. For EF; if it doesn't have a specified primary key, it will use all non-nullable columns as a compound PK (which happens here). This is now the *key* for the table/view, and thus, only one value of that key can exist. So in order to resolve this, you need to either include more columns in your view to make the auto-detected key really unique (by including e.g. the primary key of all underlying base tables), or you need to manually set the key properly.

Comment: @marc_s - first, please include your comment as an answer, I believe it qualifies and will receive an upvote. second, I double checked my "old" code using EF4, the entity in the model is the EXACT same as the EF6 entity, and the view (and underlying data) is the same too. "Old" code works fine. The only difference is using older ObjectContext templates vs new DbContext templates. Any further ideas?

Comment: Your view is incorrect, if you have EntityId and EntityType as key, then your view can never have multiple entries of Key. Entity Framework will not reload object if it has same key, it will assume that contents of rows with same primary key will always and should always be same.

Comment: @AkashKava - I allowed EF to generate the model and entity code for this view, so are you saying this is a bug in EF, or I did something wrong? From a purely SQL side, this view is obviously completely valid.

Comment: It is not bug in EF, yon just can not have multiple rows with different contents and Same key.

Comment: @AkashKava - so in my example above, why does EF still return 3 rows (with duplicate data) and not just one row?

Comment: They are not duplicates, it is same instance with multiple copies in the list, it will return one instance if you had used distinct. SQL query can result multiple rows with same key, EF will process them and will give you multiple copies of same object in the list, EF identifies entity with Key, not the contents.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same "issue" in EF4 (with an `.edmx` file using the `ObjectContext` database-first approach) - not sure why it worked for you.

For Entity Framework, if it doesn't have a specified primary key (like on a table), it will fall back to using all *non-nullable* columns of that object (here: your view) as its compound PK.

These non-nullable columns are now the key for the table/view, and thus, only one value of that key can exist.

In order to resolve this, you need to either include more columns in your view to make the auto-detected key really unique (by including e.g. the primary key of all underlying base tables), or you need to manually set the key properly to something that works for you.

Comment: So I assume there is no wholesale way to prevent this? I have to go to each entity/view and correct individually?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution I found is by setting entity's MergeOption to NoTracking.

```
 using (ContextA context = new ContextA())
{
  context.VW_MyView.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.NoTracking;
  //Rest code goes here...
}
```

Solution found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11568714/698127)