# View data in the database is difference from what EF generate

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle, entity-framework

I had trouble using distinct() from Entity Framework when I combine many tables on event ID column, so I decided to make a view in the database instead, and I just need to pull it in EF and display on the datagrid.

And EF gave me a problem I have no idea how to solve, even when I pull the SQL that EF generate, I still see nothing strange about the sql command from it...

So my view in the database generates something like this:

```
oID     TIME     LOC     NETVAL     INDIVALUE     COUNT
01     10:00     A       0.803      0.803         6
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.164         1
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.252         1
02     8:00      B       6.012      1.164         1
02     8:00      B       6.099      6.099         1
```

But, when I use EF toList() the view:

```
var query = context.MY_VIEW.toList();
datagridview1.DataSource = query;
```

I get this:

```
oID     TIME     LOC     NETVAL     INDIVALUE     COUNT
01     10:00     A       0.803      0.803         6
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.164         1
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.164         1
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.164         1
02     8:00      B       1.164      1.164         1
```

I also checked the generated sql by EF and see nothing abnormal, just simple nested statements of select from....

Comment: Looks like you are missing PrimaryKey.

Comment: Oh, so should I make primary key for the view too? The data columns from the tables that I used to create the view has no key as far as I know.

Comment: Refer this link to fix your issue. I had once similar problem.  http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/

Comment: Love u dude, thank a tons, can you post yours answer so I can vote answer when I get this working?

Comment: Not sure if you are still around, but another issue popup... Only the oID col is the PK, the rest, is nullable value, I cant create PK at all for the netval and indivalue even if i wanna try making them composite key.... is there a way to get a rowID for oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regard to antar125 answer. It doesn't workout for me very well cause I use Oracle database and Coalesce doesn't work for me.
I found a few other options and I hope it will help people that come looking for a solution for this problem.

Found same issue and people discuss here:
[Duplicate Rows when Data Binding with LINQ to Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001847/duplicate-rows-when-data-binding-with-linq-to-entities/1023997#1023997)

http://markcoleman.tumblr.com/post/25026903967/entityframework-and-a-view-with-no-primary-key

An option:
http://elegantcode.com/2012/03/15/querying-entityframework-views-without-a-key/
That one doesn't work for me as it give me exception saying there is no view in the db, might work for others.

Another way to display the view come from a legacy db (if you just want to view it) is totally bypassing EF altogether. When you drop a datagridview or w/e container that you use, please @ the designer windows, databound it with the view. It shows up correctly for me :)

Sweet!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set primary key on your view. Looks like EF is using `oID` field as the default primary key. You will have to set the primary key and then update your model. Please refer this link http://girlfromoutofthisworld.com/entity-framework-and-setting-primary-keys-on-views/