# Web API always shows the same values

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a call like this.

When I call this I become  a List of my Value but it's always the same values. Only the rows are correct. When I call this in SQL Management Studio it becomes 5 rows but in the Postman it also becomes 5 Rows but in all rows the values are the same

```
// GET: api/ablamm
[HttpGet("{schaf}")]
public IEnumerable<ablamm> Getablamm1([FromRoute]string schaf)
{
    return _context.ablamm.Where(s => s.schaf_nr == schaf);
}
```

This is the output result:

```
[
{
    "schaf_nr": "SW063R",
    "lfd_nr": 1,
    "zum_widder_datum": "2014-07-06T00:00:00",
    "ablamm_datum": "2014-12-04T00:00:00",
    "abspaenn_datum": "2015-07-18T00:00:00",
    "lamm1_nr": "SM088B",
    "lamm2_nr": "",
    "lamm3_nr": "",
    "widder_nr": "S1009",
    "bemerkung": ""
},
{
    "schaf_nr": "SW063R",
    "lfd_nr": 1,
    "zum_widder_datum": "2014-07-06T00:00:00",
    "ablamm_datum": "2014-12-04T00:00:00",
    "abspaenn_datum": "2015-07-18T00:00:00",
    "lamm1_nr": "SM088B",
    "lamm2_nr": "",
    "lamm3_nr": "",
    "widder_nr": "S1009",
    "bemerkung": ""
},
{
    "schaf_nr": "SW063R",
    "lfd_nr": 1,
    "zum_widder_datum": "2014-07-06T00:00:00",
    "ablamm_datum": "2014-12-04T00:00:00",
    "abspaenn_datum": "2015-07-18T00:00:00",
    "lamm1_nr": "SM088B",
    "lamm2_nr": "",
    "lamm3_nr": "",
    "widder_nr": "S1009",
    "bemerkung": ""
},
{
    "schaf_nr": "SW063R",
    "lfd_nr": 1,
    "zum_widder_datum": "2014-07-06T00:00:00",
    "ablamm_datum": "2014-12-04T00:00:00",
    "abspaenn_datum": "2015-07-18T00:00:00",
    "lamm1_nr": "SM088B",
    "lamm2_nr": "",
    "lamm3_nr": "",
    "widder_nr": "S1009",
    "bemerkung": ""
},
{
    "schaf_nr": "SW063R",
    "lfd_nr": 1,
    "zum_widder_datum": "2014-07-06T00:00:00",
    "ablamm_datum": "2014-12-04T00:00:00",
    "abspaenn_datum": "2015-07-18T00:00:00",
    "lamm1_nr": "SM088B",
    "lamm2_nr": "",
    "lamm3_nr": "",
    "widder_nr": "S1009",
    "bemerkung": ""
}
]
```

But when I call the SQL Select in the Management Studio it's correct:

```
SW063R  1   2014-07-06  2014-12-04  2015-07-18  SM088B             S1009    
SW063R  2   2015-07-18  2015-09-18  2016-03-18  SW092G              1009    
SW063R  3   2016-03-18  2016-08-28  2017-02-25  SW101G  SM108B      1009    
SW063R  4   2017-02-25  2017-08-10  2018-01-13  SW107G  SW108G      1010    
SW063R  5   2018-01-13  2018-06-28  NULL        SW117G  SW118G      1010
```

What's wrong with my statement?

Comment: What is the primary key in your table? Only `schaf_nr` or do you have composite key? You can try `context.ablamm..AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.schaf_nr == schaf)`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001847/duplicate-rows-when-data-binding-with-linq-to-entities

Comment: Share us the model defination for `ablamm`. Check VS output to see the generated sql query.

Comment: Thx @nemesv With your Code it works. Very good